# What is difference between */5 and 5 for minute value in crontabs?

Tags: cron, scripting, command

I have cron with following definition.

```
*/5 * * * * /somescript
```

What is the difference between them? Is second one running every 5 minutes and first is running 5 minutes after every hour?

Comment: @yoonix really of topic? are you kidding me? please do explain!?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`5 * * * *` means it runs once per hour at five minutes past the hour.

`*/5 * * * *` means it runs once every five minutes.

The later construct behaves slightly unintuitive if the number does not divide 60. For example `*/19` would run 4 times per hour at :00, :19, :38, and :57.

Comment: You can also replace the `*` with e.g. 2-59/19 which means run at :02, :21, :40, and :59.